# Laravel - Database [bootstrap] not configured

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I try using Eloquent in routes.php, but I got a message:

```
InvalidArgumentException 
Database [bootstrap] not configured.
```

My code is below:

```
$shop = Shop::where('pid', '1')->first();
```

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed configuring the database correctly.

Assuming you are on Laravel 4.0 / 4.1 / 4.2, and that you have already setup your database, go to:

app/config/database.php

and check there if you have correct credentials.

Alternative: Maybe you are using the enviroment settings, in that case, check for the database.php files in the directory inside of app/config that corresponds to your current enviroment.

Comment: I configured database correctly. When I try remove: $shop = Shop::where('pid', '1')->first();. Everything will be OK :(.

Comment: What laravel version are you using? Can you plz link the database schema also.